# What is the best way to clean a react native project?

Tags: react-native

I have a list of commands i want to run to clean a react native project. sometimes i use different computer to work on a same project and sometimes directory structures on which i keep the project files different and its get's messy.

Here is the list of commands i think will be the best. but i am confused on

```
const exec = require('shell-utils').exec;

run();

function run() {

    //exec.killPort(8081);
    //exec.execSync(`watchman watch-del-all || true`);
    //exec.execSync(`adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 || true`);
    //exec.execSync(`rm -rf lib/ios/DerivedData`);
    exec.execSync(`rm -rf android/build`);
    exec.execSync(`rm -rf android/app/build`);
    exec.execSync(`rm -rf %appdata%\Temp\react-native-*`);
    //exec.execSync(`cd android & \graldew clean`);
    exec.execSync(`npm run android`);
    //exec.execSync(`cd .. del node_modules`);
    //exec.execSync(`npm cache clean --force`);
    //exec.execSync(`npm install`);
    //exec.execSync(`npm start -- --reset-cache`);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to take a look at [react-native-clean-project](https://github.com/pmadruga/react-native-clean-project).